# CefSharp doesn't play mp3

Tags: mp3, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Is there a way to enable mp3 on my CefSharp project?
I'm looking aroung that CefSharp does not support Mp3 format. 
Is there another way to play mp3 files?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well, I didn't try anything because I do not find any working code and more, I do not know if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Due to licensing restrictions `CefSharp` is unable to support the `mp3` format. Whilst it is technically possible to recompile `CEF` with support you will need to obtain the appropriate licenses. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cefsharp/BJLMXl9c204/HMJlp8mZzF0J for a slightly outdated guide on how to compile `CEF` from source, the basics still apply.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the entire guide, but there is something wrong... Maybe because it is an old version :\
Can you provide to upgrade a new one ?

Comment: First of all. I'm trying on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 64 bit. 
May I try with this set ? All of the guide that I saw, was with windows 7 64 on visual studio 2013. 
Please, let me know

Comment: try https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cefsharp/GYP_DEFINES%7Csort:relevance/cefsharp/BJLMXl9c204/HMJlp8mZzF0J

Comment: I tryed all of em. Nothing! Is there any other guide with windows 10 ?? I don't know if there is a way to re-build cef with my os.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to enable MP3 support in CEF, but you'll have to modify the cef.gypi in the source distribution, regenerate the visual studio projects and rebuild.

Detailed build instructions:
http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding

Enabling proprietary codecs support: 
http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=371

Add 'proprietary_codecs': 1 to your cef.gypi configuration so that USE_PROPRIETARY_CODECS will be defined as required by net/base/mime_util.cc.
You'll also need proper builds of the avcodec, avformat and avutil DLLs. Luckily, you can just get these from the installation directory of Google Chrome itself ($User/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/$Version).