# alternative for web browser control and Chromium CefSharp control for wpf C#

Tags: wpf, browser, cefsharp

i need to use web pages on my wpf project and i tried to use wpf web browser control and Chromium CefSharp. my problem is web browser control does not support css transparency and Chromium CefSharp does not support html video tag with mp4 video format. Anyone know of an alternative control?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with GeckoFx, it's Windows Form Control so you should use a WindowsFormsHost as a container: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/

Answer (score 0):

Cefsharp doesn't support propietary codecs like mp4 and mp3. It supports open formats. Instead of mp4 you can convert your video to the opensource format "WEBM" and use it. If it is mp3 convert that to "ogg" then use it. Then Cefsharp will play them.

And there are some hacks, which makes Cefsharp to support propietary codecs also, Which is not legal. More information on how to support propietary codes [CefSharp doesn't play mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340037/cefsharp-doesnt-play-mp3/34606041#34606041)