# c# WPF Browser with html5 video and javascript injecting

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, html5-video, webbrowser-control

I'm searching a good webbrowser for my project but I can't find one.

1. I need html5 video streaming (doesn't work in CefSharp) and
2. I need javascript injecting (doesn't really work in the normal webbrowser)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CefSharp is able to play html5 video and audio. And [here's the list](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video) with all the supported audio and video codecs.

Just because CefSharp doesn't include proprietary Audio and Video codecs, doesn't mean it can't. Due to licensing reasons mentioned [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/873#issuecomment-214065060), CefSharp is not including them. You can however [build cef and embed your own codecs in it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143833/2005054)

You can always grab the code from their [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) and experiment your self considering [this great answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34606041/2005054)

Or you can use [GeckoFx as suggested on another answer posted on similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311487/2005054). Which is isn't really a WPF Control, but you can use it with a WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: Tried geckofx I'm getting Invalidcastexception on `var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "xulrunner");  Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(path);`